# Oracle recursive CTE for date with interval

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a recursive CTE, which generates a date/time for every 10 minutes and stops at midnight but I am struggling with the syntax and can't seem to get it to work.

I would be very appreciative to anyone who can help me out. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';


with date_rows 
(( SELECT TO_DATE('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as start_date  FROM DUAL ) 
union all
select start_date+interval '10' minute
 from date_rows
where start_date < 
TRUNC(start_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
select * from date_rows;
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Comment: @MTO I always test on live SQL so the person responding can be using the same version of Oracle I'm testing with

Comment: There is a bug in the early versions of Oracle which means that recursive sub-query factoring clauses can't handle `DATE` data types so it makes a difference if you are using Oracle 11g (maybe 12c) and earlier or if you are using later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH inputs ( value ) AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM   DUAL
),
date_rows ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         TRUNC(value) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
  FROM   inputs
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE,
         end_date
  FROM   date_rows
  WHERE  start_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE < end_date
)
SELECT start_date
FROM   date_rows;
```

or, if you want to duplicate the input value then you can use:

```sql
WITH date_rows ( start_date ) AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT start_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
  FROM   date_rows
  WHERE  start_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
           < TRUNC(TO_DATE('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
             + INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
SELECT *
FROM   date_rows;
```

*Note: At each iteration of the recursive sub-query, `start_date` is the previous value so you need to check if `start_date + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE` is before midnight (rather than just `start_date`) otherwise you will have the final row after midnight.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72818d0093e04a7f6e2adb27528808f0)*

---

What was wrong with your code:

1. For a non-recursive sub-query factoring clause, the syntax is:

   ```
   WITH query_alias AS (
   ```

   or

   ```
   WITH query_alias (column_alias) AS (
   ```

   You were missing the `AS` keyword.

   However, for a recursive sub-query factoring clause, you need to use the second version and specify the column aliases.
2. The `()` brackets around the first `SELECT` are redundant (but won't cause an error).
3. `start_date < TRUNC(start_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY)` is always going to be true, even if the date goes past the midnight boundary; so the query will recurse infinitely.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7acb65b248369072c451f2597599872)*

Comment: @MTO works great but if you have the time could you briefly explain why my attempt wasn't working so I can better mysel. Was I completely on the wrong path or was I close

Answer (score 1):

```
Something like this, I presume.

SQL> with date_rows (datum) as
  2    (select cast (to_date('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as date)
  3     from dual
  4     union all
  5     select cast (datum + interval '10' minute as date)
  6     from date_rows
  7     where datum < trunc(to_date('2021/08/20 18:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')) + interval '1' day
  8    )
  9  select * from date_rows;

DATUM
-----------------
08202021 18:30:25
08202021 18:40:25
08202021 18:50:25
08202021 19:00:25
08202021 19:10:25
08202021 19:20:25
08202021 19:30:25
08202021 19:40:25
08202021 19:50:25
08202021 20:00:25
08202021 20:10:25
<snip>    
08202021 23:20:25
08202021 23:30:25
08202021 23:40:25
08202021 23:50:25
08212021 00:00:25

34 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for responding but I believe MTO solution is easier since the date value is only used once. Having said that my final intent is to wrap this in a procedure so no user has to edit any code

Comment: thanks. I can't tell you how much time I've wasted by fixing code that QA broke by editing themselves therefore I always try to wrap code in a function or procedure so they can pass in VALUES, which will not break code. A lesson I learned well!!